# Any Stack Exchange site for discussing drawing and painting?

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

I know there are many Stack Exchange sites for different fields.  I would like to know if there are any Stack Exchange sites for discussing about drawing and painting for professional artists. If not, please add a site for Painting and Drawing.

Comment: There are a few proposal currently on [area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/1/arts) that might suit your needs.

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the [tag:site-proposal] tag, you'll see the following message: "*A placeholder for old site proposal discussions. If you have an idea for a new Stack Exchange site, you should propose it on Area 51.*"

Comment: Funny enough I don't see any site proposals for "Drawing and Painting". Closest I see is "Graphic Design" and "Pencil Drawing".